# Strange issue of Date from String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, nsdate

A Strange issue :

I am converting a String into the Date by following code :

```
NSString *dateStr = @"02/10/2012 12:00:13 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d];   
NSLog(@"Output:::-->%@",strDate);
```

I am using **Xcode 4.2**

Its working fine in **Simulator and in Device iPhone 3Gs and iPad with iOS 5.0 and iPhone 4**

But the issue is in **iPod with iOS 5.0.1**. In iPod it shows **(null)** value.

What is wrong in code ? OR is there any other issue ?

Comment: Devang's code works fine for me as well. So can you tell what actually you get as output while using Devang's code?

Comment: Do you pass the same string "02/10/2012 12:00:13 PM" as `dateStr`?

Comment: @ParthBhatt: same result (null)... one more thing the time : 12:00:13 PM is 24hr's format and I want it in 12 hr format

Comment: @ParthBhatt: also it works in iPhone 4 !!! but not in iPod !!!

Comment: I don't have an iPod. I think you should try on some other iPod. Don't know where exactly the issue is but as far as I understand it Devang's code is fine.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: nup... still... I have tested in iPhone 4 and mine and devang's code works perfectly... !!! but not in iPod ...

Comment: I will try and help you in half an hour once I reach home from office.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: did you find any fix ?

Comment: I have been trying but I succeeded installing and getting it to work on 3 of the iPods. I think issue is with your iPod or some settings within the iPod.

Comment: @ParthBhatt: are you sure your getting right time ???

Comment: Yes I do get right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!!

The problem was in the date string `NSString *dateStr = @"02/10/2012 12:00:13 PM";`

The time is in 24hr format with **"AM/PM"** I think which was wrong. **AM/PM** should be with 12hr format.

So, I just removed **AM/PM** from string and it worked !!!

also from code :

```
[dtF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Thats what parth and I have suggested you in comments.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that NSDateFormatter output can be erratic due to users' settings on their iPhones. You can force it to be standardised (I can't remember the details) by using this -

```
[dtF setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
```

...makes the whole output more predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Rather then `a` try `aaa`

Replace your code with following :

```
NSString *dateStr = @"02/10/2012 12:00:13 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aaa"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:d];   
NSLog(@"Output:::-->%@",strDate);
```

Output:::-->`February 10, 2012 12:00 PM`

Comment: @Maulik : Clean and rebuild it.

Comment: one more thing the time : 12:00:13 PM is 24hr's format and I want it in 12 hr format

Comment: @Maulik : I think you should google it. Or check `HH` or `hh`. Just observe it. you will get your output.

Comment: @Maulik: Use `hh` to make it to 12 hour format. I think the code in the answer makes it to 12 hour format, which is what you want.

Comment: My code is working in Simulator and iPhone 3Gs and iPad with iOS 5.0 and iPhone 4 expect iPod !!! I don't understand whats wrong with iPod..

Comment: @Maulik : Get new one. Or try with different iPod.